# return String from database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my **Model** :

```
function getAvenuName($id) {
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('admin.username');
        $this->db->from('personal_closest');
        $this->db->join('admin', 'admin.id = personal_closest.avenu_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('personal_closest.avenu_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();        
    }
```

This is my **Controller** :

```
foreach ($listofcloset['postByUser'] as $key => $value) { 
            $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['calculatetime']   =  $this->calculatetime(strtotime($value['postdatetime']));
            $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['countcomments']   =  $this->countcomments($value['id']); 
            $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['comments']        =  $this->comments->sltpostcomments($value['personal_closest_id']); 
            $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['countCloset']     =  $this->closet->countCloset($value['id']);            
            $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['givencool']       =  $this->checkCoolIsGiven($this->session->userdata('user_id'),$value['user_id'],$value['personal_closest_id']);
            $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['givencloset']     =  count($this->closet->selectIdbycloset($this->session->userdata('user_id'),$value['user_id'],$value['personal_closest_id']));
            if (empty($listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['username'])){
                $listofcloset['postByUser'][$key]['username'] = $this->personal_closest->getAvenuName($value['avenu_id']);
            }
        }
```

When i go to take the username i've a problem with array to string conversion. I'm trying to found a solution to take just the String instaed the array.

That's the result:

```
[username] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [username] => USER1
                    )

            )
```

Comment: try replacing `$query->result()` with `$query->result_array()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get it :)

```
function getAvenuName($id) {
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('admin.username');
    $this->db->from('personal_closest');
    $this->db->join('admin', 'admin.id = personal_closest.avenu_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('personal_closest.avenu_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();
    return $result->username;  
}
```

Comment: I changed result to $result to avoid confusion for anyone else that may need this. And you're very welcome. I'm glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code you will get direct array

```
function getAvenuName($id) {
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('admin.username');
    $this->db->from('personal_closest');
    $this->db->join('admin', 'admin.id = personal_closest.avenu_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('personal_closest.avenu_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();        
}
```

Comment: This is good but print me always an array and i need a String 
[username] => Array
                (
                    [username] => Mywardrobe
                )
Infact in the View i got this error:

Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion